# Unexpected behavior of a switch statement in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, switch-statement

The code below displays even the case 20, but my `int x` is equal to 10 only.
What I want to happen is if `x` = 10, then I should show case 10 only. The problem is that it also shows case 20.

```
public class For_Loop {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  for (int x = 10; x <= 20; x++){ 
   switch (x) {

    case 10:
        System.out.println ("Ten");
        break;

    case 20:
        System.out.println ("Twenty");
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println ("None");
        break;  
    }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: you should edit your post to fix  the indent. Then what's wrong ?  what's your error message if any ? what behavior ?

Comment: YOU should tell us what is wrong with it

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: [SO is not for code dumps](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88842/discourage-code-dumps). Please describe your problem, steps you've taken to try solving it, etc.

Comment: Ten
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
Twenty

Process completed. this is the problem... even the default "none" shows up

Comment: and what are you expecting

Comment: Can you explain what's your main idea? What this code supposed to do? Because the output you specified is completely correct

Comment: @JoeyEguna That is exactly what your code should be doing...

Comment: my int x valus is 10... but when i run it it also shows twenty and none which is my case 20: and default: ... i just want to show case 10: because the value of my X is 10...

Comment: `x` is 10, 11 ... 20 because you are executing a loop...

Comment: If you just want to show case 10: because the value of your X is 10, then set x=10 and remove the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

condition should be incrementing by 10:
`for (int x = 10; x <= 20; x=x+10)`

Answer (score 1):

for all numbers 11 to 19 none will show up as it is the default value and the numbers are not in the switch case